# How do I git rebase from master in fewer commands when I have local file changes

Tags: git, rebase

If I am working on a feature branch, and I want to fetch and rebase in changes from the master branch, is there a shorter way to do it than this?

```
git stash
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout my-feature-branch
git rebase master
git stash pop
```

Note how I have to stash too, because I have edited a config file that I don't want to commit.

How can I do this in fewer commands?

Comment: I think you don't need `git checkout master` and then `git checkout my-feature-branch', just pull and rebase

Comment: @Alexan that would do rebase only with local version of master branch. He might be able to do `git rebase origin/master` but that would ignore commits in local master that are not pushed into origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One line version:

```
git pull --rebase --autostash origin master
```

Comment: git pull doesn't pull all the branches by default.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can write a script for this.

I think against git rebase master is better git merge master --no-ff

If you use gitflow, there are some maven plugin to make a feature branch
or finish feature branch etc. But the feature branch is from develop branch not from master.

Answer (score 0):

If you have zsh you can use oh-my-zsh, which provides an alias for git rebase master that's just `grbm`