# git pull to different branch

Tags: git, pull

I am working on a feature branch, my master branch is set up to track origin/master. I want to pull changes into master from origin/master that have been merged in without having to switch to master from my feature branch. How would I do that?

Comment: `git fetch origin master:master`

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is such an option honestly for pull, since it's a `git fetch` and a `git merge` one after the other. But what you can do is create a `git alias` that will do it for you.

You can put this into your global (or local) `gitconfig`

```
[alias]
    pull-into = "!p() { git checkout $1 && git pull --rebase && git checkout - ; }; p"
```

This will create a `git pull-into` alias, where it just defines a bash function called `p`. You pass to it the branch you want to pull from. It goes to it, `pull --rebase`'s it on it (or you can just have `git pull` if you just need that) and then goes back to your previous branch.

You can invoke it like so and it will give such an output

```
# currently on branch featurex
git pull-into master

Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by X commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch) 
Updating 7699151..23b27bf
Fast-forward
<CHANGES AND SO ON>
Current branch master is up to date.
Switched to branch 'featurek'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/featurex'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need to do that? A more common desire is to update *your* branch from the current remote state of `master`. And that is something you can readily do without leaving your branch:

1. `fetch` to update all remote-tracking branches, including `origin/master`
2. `merge origin/master` (into your current branch) — actually I prefer to rebase, it's up to you

Now the remote state of `master` is part of your branch, and the differences are thus minimized. That is most likely your actual goal.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53437238/240564